# What is wrong with this sql innerjoin?

Tags: sql-server-2005, inner-join

Here is my select statement with the innerjoin of two tables,

```
if not exists(select EmpId from SalaryDetails 
              where EmpId in (select Emp_Id 
                              from Employee where Desig_Id=@CategoryId))
begin
  // some statements here
end
else
begin
  SELECT e.Emp_Id, e.Identity_No, e.Emp_Name,
      case WHEN e.SalaryBasis=1 THEN 'Weekly' 
           ELSE 'Monthly' end as SalaryBasis,e.FixedSalary,
      (SELECT TOP 1 RemainingAdvance 
       FROM SalaryDetails 
       ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) as Advance
    FROM Employee as e inner join Designation as d on e.Desig_Id=d.Desig_Id 
    INNER JOIN SalaryDetails as S on e.Emp_Id=S.EmpId 
End
```

My results pane,

[alt text http://img220.imageshack.us/img220/7774/resultpane.jpg](http://img220.imageshack.us/img220/7774/resultpane.jpg)

And My SalaryDetails Table,

[alt text http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/770/salarydettable.jpg](http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/770/salarydettable.jpg)

**EDIT:**
My Output must be,

> 16  CR14      Natarajan Weekly 150.00
>   354.00
>  17  cr12333 Pandian   Weekly 122.00   0.00

Comment: It might help if you gave us a clue as to what is wrong with your output. I can't figure it out, nor am I willing to.

Comment: @Lieven, was just about to make the same comment - I have made a guess that he's always getting 354 for the Advance whereas he has differing values in the SalaryDetails - I could could be way off the mark, though.

Comment: You are right but that has nothing to do with the inner joins.

Comment: @lieven look at my if not exist statement it return two employee Id's 16,17

Comment: So the question is *why is the else clause executed io the then clause*?

Comment: @Lieven see my edit... I know its the else will be executed ... But my result pane should be my edit...

Comment: So the if not exist statement has nothing to do with it.  Evidently both users exist because you're getting them back in the results - the question should be why are you getting duplicated records, surely?  In which case I would say to you, you've got multiple records in your SalaryDetails for employees 16 and 17, but you're not filtering or grouping them to get one record per employee back, so SQL's giving you all records.  You need to filter or group.

Comment: Well, looking at your data, just add DISTINCT in front of it and implement the solution given by Andy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your join to Designation isn't even used and you're also missing your WHERE clause that you used in the IF statement at the top. I'd also move the subquery down into the join like Andy pointed out. Without having the DB to test against this probably won't be exact but I'd rewrite it to something like;

```
SELECT e.Emp_Id, e.Identity_No, e.Emp_Name,
  case WHEN e.SalaryBasis=1 
       THEN 'Weekly' 
       ELSE 'Monthly' end as SalaryBasis,
  e.FixedSalary,S.RemainingAdvance as Advance
FROM Employee as e 
  INNER JOIN (
   SELECT TOP 1 EmpId, RemainingAdvance 
   FROM SalaryDetails 
   ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) as S on e.Emp_Id=S.EmpId 
WHERE e.Desig_Id=@CategoryId
```

Andy's suggestion to move the subquery into a view is a good one, much easier to read and probably a lot more efficient if the DB is large.

**EDIT: (ANSWER)**

```
(SELECT sd.empid,
               sd.remainingadvance,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sd.empid ORDER BY sd.createddate DESC) AS rank
          FROM SALARYDETAILS sd
          JOIN EMPLOYEE e ON e.emp_id = sd.empid
                         AND e.desig_id = @CategoryId) s
            WHERE s.rank = 1
```

I edited jay's answer because he came close to my output...

Comment: Just a tip Jay, your TOP 1 in the subquery is going to be applied before the EmpID in the join, so if you have 2 records in SalaryDetails with EmpID 16 and 17 with 16 being first when sorted by CreatedDesc, and your join has an e.Emp_Id of 17, it won't match the SELECT TOP 1 ... query.  I've fell for this mistake before - it actually wasn't noticed until about 6 months later, oops!  You have to use RANK() to get the TOP 1 per employee ID.

Comment: @Jay13 it works for me... But i get only one row .... My categoryId gives Two empIds `16,17`...

Answer (score 3):

You're not filtering the sub-query (`SELECT TOP 1 RemainingAdvance FROM SalaryDetails ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC`) on any employee ID, so it's giving you the first record in the entire table when sorted by `CreatedDate DESC` (which I'm guessing is 354.)

You will probably want to move that table expression into your FROM clause, not your SELECT, include your employee ID, and do a join on that expression.

```
SELECT 
    e.Emp_Id,e.Identity_No,e.Emp_Name,case WHEN e.SalaryBasis=1 THEN 'Weekly' ELSE 'Monthly' end as SalaryBasis,e.FixedSalary,
    from Employee as e inner join Designation as d on e.Desig_Id=d.Desig_Id 
    inner join SalaryDetails as S on e.Emp_Id=S.EmpId 
    inner join
    (SELECT EmpID, RemainingAdvance, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) AS SalaryRank FROM SalaryDetails ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) as Advance ON Advance.EmpID = e.Emp_ID AND Advance.SalaryRank = 1
```

This is just off the top of my head so may take a bit of tweaking to run correctly.  Note also the use of the RANK() function - if you use TOP 1, you're only ever getting the first record of the entire table.  What you need is the first record *per employee ID*.

If this was me I would probably make that table expression a view or even a scalar-valued function taking your employee ID and returning the first RemainingAdvance value, then you could use TOP 1 and filter on the employee ID.

Comment: @Andy look at my if not exist statement it reurn two employee Id's 16,17

Comment: +1 In light of not knowing what is actually wrong, this is the best educated guess I guess.

Comment: I didn't provide a view in my answer.  You can create one just by moving the table expression (SELECT...FROM Advance) into a view then joining that the same as if it were a table.  Sorry, but we're here to make suggestions, not do your work for you.

Comment: That was my suggestion - putting the code to create the view in my answer would be giving you the answer ;-)